# How to find in java that a jsf component has been removed using jquery?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am bound to remove a primefaces component only from client side. I am using jquery `remove()` for that.

As I can not set `rendered=false` from client side, so I am just trying to count or find in backend controller that the removed component is absent. After removing, I inspected the page html and the component is no more in dom. But before and after removing the component, I get the same value of child count (non zero) fetched through `FacesContext`:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("htmlGeneratedComponentId").getChildCount();
```

I know `FacesContext` won't know that the element has been removed by some client side script. JSF wouldn't know anything as no communication has been made to JSF and `rendered` attribute will remain true as checked by:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("htmlGeneratedComponentId").isRendered();
```

Right now, my requirement is that after removing a component using client side script I need to find in my java controller, a way to know that the component has been removed even if the `rendered` attribute is still true.

Answer (score 2):

Pass that information via an additional request parameter which you could check in the `rendered` attribute of the component in question.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <input type="hidden" id="fooRemovedByClient" name="fooRemovedByClient" />
    ...
    <x:someComponent id="foo" rendered="#{not param.fooRemovedByClient}" />
</h:form>
```

And let jQuery set it accordingly on remove:

```
$foo.remove();
$("#fooRemovedByClient").val("true");
```

Needless to say that this is hacky. You'd better just let jQuery toggle the `rendered` attribute via a JSF/PrimeFaces ajax call. The [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) is useful in this.

Comment: I very much agree with the last paragraph above. You NEED to remove it client side but still need to know about it server side. Strange requirement

Comment: @BalusC I am trying to pass EL expression as method argument via an ajax call like this:
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{myCdiView.onTabChange(accountingQueryView.gridRemovedByClient)}"/>

But following does not work:

public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event, String gridRemovedByClient) {
}

I need event object also in the method and above method signature does not work.